# AWS EMR spark-scala job failing with AWS Datapipeline: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to run a spark scala application on Amazon EMR cluster using Amazon Data-Pipeline. The step was added as follows in EMRActivity:

```
command-runner.jar,spark-submit,--deploy-mode,cluster,--class,com.demo.GettingStarted,s3://myBucket/sampleApps/HelloWorld.jar
```

After looking into the EMR logs, the job is failing consistently with following stack trace:

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application

```
application_1517065923932_0001 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1034)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1081)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
```

What may be the possbile cause of this error?

This is a sample app that prints Hello World to console.

The same job works on AWS EMR.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the application logs in Resource Manager. If you enable Hue service in EMR, you can able to view the logs from UI. In Hue,go to workflows --> DashBoard -> workflow and see the job and container logs. I suspect that there might be chance that Oozie couldn't able to parse the spark-defaults.conf parameters.

When I configured the following properties in spark-defaults.conf, Oozie couldn't able to parse the configuration if it contains spaces in oozie version 4.3.0.

spark.driver.extraJavaOptions    -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled  true
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons I think is that you should specify the path of the jar as `{input.directoryPath}/HelloWorld.jar`,where the input.directoryPath comes from using the S3DataNode.

It would be better though if you can find the exact logs.

To view the logs generated by the driver/executor,go to :  p`ipelineLogUri->EmrClusterId->{latest_run}->containers->application->containe`r. The last step i.e container, for driver logs select the container having id:-1, and the rest of the logs (2,3,4...) will be logs generated via the executor instances.